# formatiing part text in a table cell in word

Tags: text, ms-word, underline

`tab1.Rows(20).Cells.Merge
tab1.Rows(20).Cells(1).Range.Text = "2.   Brief of Case.  " + objVar(6)
tab1.Rows(20).Cells(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify

tab1.Rows(22).Cells.Merge
tab1.Rows(22).Cells(1).Range.Text = "2.   Present Status of the Case.  " + objVar(8)
tab1.Rows(22).Cells(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify`

I want the text in the row 20 cell 1 "Brief of Case" only to be bold and underlined ...rest of the text to be normal and similarly the text in row 22 cell 1 "Present Status of the Case" to be undelrlined and bold

`tab1.Rows(20).Cells.Merge
tab1.Rows(20).Cells(1).Range.Text = "2.   Brief of Case.  " + objVar(6)
tab1.Rows(20).Cells(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify

tab1.Rows(22).Cells.Merge
tab1.Rows(22).Cells(1).Range.Text = "2.   Present Status of the Case.  " + objVar(8)
tab1.Rows(22).Cells(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify`

Comment: And what's your question about all this?

Comment: I want the text in the row 20 cell 1 "Brief of Case" only to be bold and underlined ...rest of the text to be normal and similarly the text in row 22 cell 1 "Present Status of the Case" to be undelrlined and bold. How do i code for it in excel VBA

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Adding a tag for the programming language could also help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Dim Rng As Range
With tab1
  With .Rows(20)
    .Cells.Merge
    Set Rng = .Cells(1).Range
    With Rng
      .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
      .Text = objVar(6)
      .Collapse wdCollapseStart
      .Text = "2. Brief of Case. "
      .Font.Bold = True
      .Font.Underlined = True
    End With
  End With
  With .Rows(22)
    .Cells.Merge
    Set Rng = .Cells(1).Range
    With Rng
      .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
      .Text = objVar(8)
      .Collapse wdCollapseStart
      .Text = "2. Present Status of the Case. "
      .Font.Bold = True
      .Font.Underlined = True
    End With
  End With
End With
```

Comment: the output required is in following format
2.     Brief of Case. .................. ( only the Text "Brief of Case" to be bold and underlined and balance text being input from array varobj(6) to be normal and justified

Comment: Dim strValue1 As String
 Dim strValue2 As String
             
        strValue1 = "Brief of Case: " + (Sheets("Petitions").Cells(nPET, 9).FormulaR1C1) + vbNewLine + vbNewLine
        strValue2 = "Present Status of the Case: " + (Sheets("Petitions").Cells(nPET, 34).FormulaR1C1)
        Sheets("Summary_Petitions").Cells(nOpenRecords - 1, 5).Value = strValue1 + strValue2
similarly in the above code how can i  make the Text "Brief of Case" and "Present status of the case" as underlined and bold ?